# HPQC - Using Script editor to add functionality in TestPlan

Tags: hp-quality-center

I want to add few functionalities to a newly added button in "TestPlan" toolbar in HPQC. I browsed through the script editor in HPQC, but I am not sure how the code delivery is done (process). Please share with me any links/pointers which might be helpful.

Comment: Update: I found the HP ALM OTA Refernce in my HPQC installation and it is quite useful in understanding the objects, interfaces and methods used. But I am not able to use the interface methods as mentioned in the examples in the reference as it is in VB and the actual workflow scripts are in VB scripts. I understand though not much difference between the 2, I am stuck with using the interfaces in my procedures. I am not able to use `Dim var As Interface1`. it throws me error while compiling. `Dim var` solves the issue, but How to use the `Interface1` ?

Comment: just using the interface without declaring worked, following is the sample `clipboard = iscp.CopyToClipBoard(sourceFolder.NodeID, 0, sourceFolderPath)`